# How to handle Multiple request as a Microservice

Tags: python, deep-learning, request, synchronization

I currently have to detect person on 5 camera stream with a hardware of 1 RTX2080Ti GPU. How can i be able to handle them an archive real-time constraint.

i have tried to use mxnet yolo and found that it worked best when i inserted a batch of 14 images to 2 seperated yolo microservices which archived ~30fps each => I can consecutively put a batch of frames from 2 stream to 1 yolo microservices with the cost of 0.5second delayed. But then i'm still stuck with the last stream, i don't know how to stack them with others

I think skipping frames is not avoidable but how to synchronize the results and give back the results to each requester.
Thanks.